# LINQ to SQL - populate child property of a collection property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ef-code-first

I'm using Code First and LINQ to SQL in an ASP.NET MVC4 project. In the below query I'm trying to populate PatientView.Appointments.ScheduledBy, but it's returning null.  I've tried adding .Include("Appointments.ScheduledBy"), but Appointments.ScheduledBy continues to return null.

How can I modify the LINQ to SQL expression to get ScheduledBy populated?

Here's my LINQ to SQL (Id is the action's parameter)

```
var q = from p in context.Patients.Include("Appointments.ScheduledBy")
        where p.Id == Id
        select new PatientView
        {
             Patient = p,
             Appointments = p.Appointments.OrderByDescending(a => a.ScheduledFor)
        };
PatientView pv = q.Single();
```

PatientView is the view model for the view.  The Appointments property does get populated, but the Appointments' ScheduledBy property is null.

```
public class PatientView
{
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Patient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public Employee ScheduledBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ScheduledFor { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How can the `Appointment`'s `ScheduledFor` property be null if it is a non-nullable `DateTime`?

Comment: I think you are not using Linq to Sql but Linq to Entities. Linq to Sql is something that is not related to Code First (or Entity Framework)

Comment: @armen.shimoon - That was a typo on my part.  "the Appointments' ScheduledFor property is null" should have been "the Appointments' ScheduledBy property is null", and I have since edited the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Pawel I honestly don't know which is being executed (LINQ to Entities or LINQ to SQL) or how I can tell. I know that I used Code First to create the database and I use LINQ expressions to get data out of and into the DB, but I'm not clear LINQ-wise where the dividing line is between LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities.

Comment: If you are using System.Data.Entity/DbContext/ObjectContext namespace you are using Linq to Entities.